# How to exit gracefully from an assertion failure in a multithreaded application

Tags: c++, c++11, assert

In a multi-threaded application, I use the following ASSERT macro **to catch coding and data errors during debug unit-testing**.

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define ASSERT(condition, message) \
do { \
    if (! (condition)) { \
        std::cerr << "Assertion `" #condition "` failed in " << __FILE__ \
        << " line " << __LINE__ << ": " << message << std::endl; \
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); \
    } \
} while (false)
#else
#define ASSERT(condition, message) do { } while( false )
#endif
```

It essentially does what I need, except for the nasty `std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` that seriously needs replacing.  In its current form, I get double-deletes and all sorts of nastiness which obfuscates the assertion message.

**How do I exit gracefully from an assertion failures in a multithreaded app**?

Perhaps I should throw from the assertion and then `catch + return(1)` from `main()`?
(I'm not sure the consequences of doing this, so I'm totally open to various options)

Comment: Yes, throw an exception. Read up on exception propagation in a multi-threaded environment, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB - ty - I will start googling on the topic

Comment: @KerrekSB: The problem with throwing an exception is that by the time the exception is caught, the context of the error is lost, which makes it harder to determine the cause of the error.

Comment: @Mankarse: I thought the error message takes care of printing out the necessary contextual information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's quick and dirty, `_exit` works perfectly on most platforms.

Comment: +1 ty - this seems to work - could you elaborate on what actually happens with _exit()?  (I will also google)  I might have use for this call in other contexts if I can understand its limitations.

Comment: It does a semi-immediate, unconditional, graceless termination of the calling process.